# How to select just one element in GridView with multiples array?

Tags: arrays, flutter, gridview

I´ve got 3 arrays. If I pick on letter "G" for example, I want just to select letter "G" container. Instead it select me all array[index]. How can I just select one Container?

```
  var array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  var array2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"];
  var array3 = ["I", "J", "K", "L"];
  var paramselected = 0;

  gridView(List<String> arrayParam) {
    return GridView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
      itemCount: arrayParam.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {[enter image description here][1]
            setState(() {
              paramselected = index;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: (paramselected == index) ? Colors.blue[50] : Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                arrayParam[index],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[that is what i´ve got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxvur.png)

Comment: You basically have 3 gridviews im guessing ?, if yes, you need to keep each gridview selected index in a separate state, cant use the same `paramselected'

Comment: ``` 
ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          gridView(array1),
          gridView(array2),
          gridView(array3),
        ],
      ),
``` 
Yep, you are right. That is what I´ve got. Anyway, I didn´t find a way of keep each gridview´s selected index in separated states...

Comment: You can add a `selectedGrid` state to seperate in wich grid the `paramSelected` is pointing at. ex: the letter 'G' is in the second grid so your state would look like `selectedGrid = 2; paramSelected = 2`

Comment: Allthought if iam allowed to ask, why are you using 3 gridviews instead of just one ?

Comment: Sure! I will try right now. I am using 3 gridviews because there are 3 arrays. This example its just a small version of what I was doing. And having the info into arrays was the best solution. I can´t save all the info in one array unfortunately

Comment: @SlahLayouni thank You mate! it works!

Comment: glad to hear that !